# What does Virtual Bytes mean in Worker Processes pane in IIS7.5 Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5

What does Virtual Bytes mean in Worker Processes pane in IIS7.5 Manager?

If I open IIS Manager (On WindowsServer 2008r2), and go to the Worker Processes page, I can see that one of my AppPool processes reports

```
Private Bytes (KB) 106,435.00
Virtual Bytes (KB) 748,788.00
```

However, if I look at task manager, the associated w3wp.exe process reports `69,276K`.

Can anyone explain to me how these figures relate to each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273%28WS.10%29.aspx) should help to explain:

> **Private Bytes (KB).** The current size
>   of memory committed to a worker
>   process, which cannot be shared with
>   other processes. This corresponds to
>   **Virtual Memory Size** in Windows Task
>   Manager.
>
> **Virtual Bytes (KB).** The current size
>   of the virtual address space for a
>   worker process. This does not
>   correspond to anything in Windows Task
>   Manager.

The memory showing in task manager is the amount of physical memory in use by the process that cannot be shared with other processes.

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help explain Virtual Address Space:

> A virtual address does not represent
>   the actual physical location of an
>   object in memory; instead, the system
>   maintains a *page table* for each
>   process, which is an internal data
>   structure used to translate virtual
>   addresses into their corresponding
>   physical addresses. Each time a thread
>   references an address, the system
>   translates the virtual address to a
>   physical address.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that before. I've updated the answer with the definitions (needs peer reviewing).  However, I still don't really understand what Virtual Bytes represents.  What is meant by 'Virtual Address Space'?

Comment: Additional info added about Virtual Address Space.

Comment: Thanks for the update Rob. Does anyone really understand this though? I don't think I do.  For instance, if virtual addresses are just pointers to physical addresses, then what does the size of the 'the current size of the virtual address space' mean?